# Comparator for Generic Interface Without Warnings

Tags: java, generics, comparator

Given:

```
public interface PrimaryKey<Key extends Comparable> {
    Key getKey();
}
```

and

```
public class PrimaryKeyComparator implements Comparator<PrimaryKey> {
    public int compare(PrimaryKey first, PrimaryKey second) {
        return first.getKey().compareTo(second.getKey());
    }
}
```

This combination works, but gives warnings about raw types. I've tried various ways of adding the type arguments, but every combination I've tried breaks the code.

Comment: Using `Key` and `TKey` as a generic placeholders is a really easy way to confuse people reading your code.  There's a reason Java uses `E`, `T`, `K`, and `V` as placeholder names.

Comment: Absolutely agree with R. Bemrose. `Key` looks like the name of a class or interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface PrimaryKey<TKey extends Comparable<TKey>> {
    TKey getId();
}

public class PrimaryKeyComparator<TKey extends Comparable<TKey>> 
                                 implements Comparator<PrimaryKey<TKey>> {
    public int compare(PrimaryKey<TKey> first, PrimaryKey<TKey> second) {
        return first.getId().compareTo(second.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: The generic parameter `TKey` should really be `<K extends Comparable<? super K>>` which allows the use of classes that implement the raw `Comparable` and not `Comparable<T>`, or subclasses of a `Comparable<T>` class.